# Random Number Guesser

Tags: python, random

So, Im a complete newb when it comes to programming. I have been watching tutorials and I am reading a book on how to program python. So,  I want to create a number generator guesser on my own and I have watched some tutorials on it but I do not want to recreate the code. basically, I want to make my own guesser with the information I've gotten.

```
import random

# Random Numbergenerator Guesser

print("Hello and welcome to the random number guesser.")
print("I am guessing a number of 1 - 20. Can you guess which one?")

x = random.randint(1,20)

# Here you guess the number value of 'x'
for randomNumber in range (1,7):
    randomGuess = input()
    if randomGuess > x:
        print("Too high. Guess again!")
    elif randomGuess < x:
        print("Too low. Guess again!")
    else:
        break

# Checks to see if the number you were guessing is correct or takes you to a fail screen.
if randomGuess == x:
    print("Correct number!")
else:
    print("Too many tries. You have failed. The number I was thinking of was " + (x))``
```

I keep getting this error.

```
 C:\Python\Python35\python.exe "C:/Users/Morde/Desktop/Python Projects/LoginDataBase/LoginUserDatabse1File.py"
Hello and welcome to the random number guesser.
I am guessing a number of 1 - 20. Can you guess which one?
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Morde/Desktop/Python     Projects/LoginDataBase/LoginUserDatabse1File.py", line 12, in <module>
    if randomGuess > x:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: Use `randomGuess = int(input())`.

Comment: `input()` returns a string (`str` object), you need to create an `int` object from the string.

Answer (score 0):

First, your formating is bad. Second, error is raised because You're comparing `string` (which You get from `input()`) and `integer`. You should convert input value to `integer` using:

```
randomGuess = int(input())
```

Comment: I changed it to exactly and now Im getting another error saying its faulty.    randomGuess = int(input)()
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: In the answer it is mentioned to do: `int(input())` check `()` around `input()` vs yours around `input`

Comment: Exactly as @anonymous said. `int()` function will take input parameter `input()`. So, `int(input())` and not `int(input)()`.

Answer (score 0):

the error is at this line:

```
if randomGuess > x: print("Too high. Guess again!")
```

because you try to compare a integer `x` to a string `randomGuess`
and `randomGuess` is a string because you define it like this:

```
randomGuess = input()
```

you can do:

```
randomGuess = int(input())
```

to force python to consider your guess number as a integer (but you have to handle the case when the user inputs something else than a integer)

Comment: I am still getting an error. It now says.
File "C:/Users/Morde/Desktop/Python Projects/LoginDataBase/LoginUserDatabse1File.py", line 9, in <module>
    randomGuess = int(input)()
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. I did: 'randomGuess= int(input)()' instead of randomGuess = int(input())